# Is it possible to create a HTML push parser with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, parsing, screen-scraping, nokogiri, sax

I'm trying to parse large HTML documents and extract information from them, so that I can create JSON documents with just the data that I want. I'm currently using a Nokogiri::HTML::SAX::Parser to parse the HTML document and it works great; but to speed things up I'd like to use something closer to the [Nokogiri::XML::SAX::PushParser](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/PushParser.html), so that I can begin the parse whilst I'm downloading the HTML document.

[I've tried playing around](https://gist.github.com/1376053) with Nokogiri to throw in a HTML SAX parser with the PushParser, but it keeps giving me syntax errors because it still treats the input document as XML. There might be a good reason why you can't use a push parser approach with HTML, because of malformed tags and so on, but I was wondering whether there is a way of using Nokogiri's PushParser with HTML documents?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible with Nokogiri. (Posted as a comment rather than an answer as I am not certain of it.)

Answer (score 0):

In December 2011, Nokogiri added its [HTML Push Parser](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/SAX/PushParser.html). So I suppose this answers the question of whether it is possible.